# Spontaneous symmetry breaking induced by pure Chern-Simons field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, symmetry-breaking, chern-simons-theory

Maybe this is more of a reference request, but I'd also like an explanation of the example (if there is one). An answer with just a reference would suffice though.

Simply put, are there any known $(2+1)d$ QFT's with fermion matter in which a pure Chern-Simons field is the cause of a $0$ form symmetry spontaneously breaking? Maybe another way to phrase it is if there are known examples in which a $0$ form symmetry is spontaneously broken in the strongly coupled limit of $(2+1)d$ Yang-Mills?

Comment: Strong coupling is hard, there aren't many examples that I know of where it is sufficiently understood. Your question may not have a known answer. Does the SSB of baryon number in https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07720 satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Flavour symmetry is also supposedly broken in https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08755, see also related work by Seiberg and collaborators.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform In your last reference, the only mention of the gauge coupling is in assuming it is much smaller than the fermion masses in the broken phase. Is the broken phase supposed to still hold in the strong coupling limit?

Comment: Perhaps a mixed anomaly between the one-form symmetry of CS and some zero-form symmetry, in a way that the one-form symmetry cannot spontaneously break and there is no non-trivially gapped phase to saturate the anomaly inducing finally the zero-form symmetry to break? Sounds like a pretty made-up scenario and I don't have any references where it happens, but could be feasible.

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher These papers claim to identify the entire phase diagram. Recall that in $d<4$ gauge theories are superrenormalizable, i.e., the gauge coupling has strictly positive mass dimension. In particular, $m\to0$ is equivalent to $g\to+\infty$, because the effective (dimensionless) coupling constant is $g^2/m$. So the "small mass" (intermediate) phase is the strongly coupled phase. And the "large mass" (asymptotic) phases are the weakly coupled phases.